# Effective wooden board cutting algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I need to come up with an algorithm for cutting wooden boards with minimum waste left. The cutting machine cuts in straight lines; it can't stop halfway to e.g. turn 90° and continue.

**Example:**
I have a wooden board with dimensions 280cm x 207cm and need to minimize the waste after the cutting process.

I have the following set of table widths and lengths.

**Width**
140
140
140
197
197
30,5
30,5

**Length**
33
33
33
33
33
33
33

I am thinking about using "Greedy algorithm" since the length is always the same.
Any ideas?

Comment: Cut them to what shape? If you start from one side and cut all the way to the other side in a straight line, what's considered "waste"?

Comment: Even though the lengths are all the same, greedy won't give minimal waste (except accidentally).

Comment: That machine can turn around, but not in the process. So basically as "waste" is considered leftovers that can be used again.

Comment: https://optimalprograms.com/cutting-optimization/ worked for me.  (I'm not affiliated, and used their free trial.)  I had to cut about 250 boards of various lengths from 12, 16 and 20' stock.  It took a little while to figure out how it worked, but it did a good job.  I was able to cut and paste the input data into it, and was able to export the csv output file back into a spreadsheet for further processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a variant of 2D bin packing, which is NP hard. A common approximation to it is sorting the pieces by width and then start cutting out pieces from the smallest remaining board that still suffices. Read more about this and more complex algorithms at http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html